# Nested pymongo queries (mlab)

Tags: pymongo

I have some documents in mlab mongodb; the format is:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58aeb1d074fece33edf2b356"
    },
    "sensordata": {
        "operation": "chgstatus",
        "user": {
            "status": "0",
            "uniqueid": "191b117fcf5c"
        }
    },
    "created_date": {
        "$date": "2017-02-23T15:26:29.840Z"
    }
}
```

> database name : mparking_sensor
>
> collection name : sensor

I want to query in python to extract status key value pair and created_date key value pair only.

my python code is :

```
    import sys
import pymongo
uri = 'mongodb://thorburn:tekush1!@ds157529.mlab.com:57529/mparking_sensor'


client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
db = client.get_default_database().sensor
print db
results = db.find()

for record in results:

 print(record["sensordata"] , record['created_date'])

print()

client.close()
```

which gives me everything under `sensordata` as expected, dot notations giving me an error, can somebody help?

Comment: I tried using    print(record['sensordata':{'user':{'status':'1'}}]) .. unhashable error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyMongo represents BSON documents as Python dictionaries, and subdocuments as dictionaries within dictionaries. To access a value in a nested dictionary:

```
record["sensordata"]["user"]["status"]
```

So a complete print statement might be:

```
print("%s %s" % (record["sensordata"]["user"]["status"], record['created_date']))
```

That prints:

```
0 {'$date': '2017-02-23T15:26:29.840Z'}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked . But i cant find '$date' key , only the values.                   Example output: 0 2017-02-24 18:45:03.449000